# Remainder of one sum is greater than another full sum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation

> Let $0<q<p$, $0<x_k<1$, with $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k =0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^p <\infty$
>
> I want to show, that $\exists n_0 \forall m\ge n_0$ and $n$ large enough:
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^p<\sum_{k=m}^n x_k^q$ thus following $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^q=\infty$

Intuitively this is somehow  clear, but what would be the rigorous way?
Of course, we know that there exist $N$ s.t.$\forall j,m>N:$ $\sum_{k=j}^m x_k^p < \epsilon$ , $\forall \epsilon >0$

I tried splitting up the sum in various way, but always ended up with something either trivial or  useless.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is as stated? As is, the assertion is false. Also, is it $x$ (fixed) and not $x_k$?

Comment: Actually it is $x_k$ where $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k =0$ I assumed it to be correct for $x$ fixed aswell by I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

As written, the inequality is always true (with $n_0=1$), since $x_k^p<x_k^q$ for all $k$.

It does not follow, though that the series for $x_k^q$ diverges: for an easy example take $x_k=1/k$, $q=2$, $p=3$, where both series converge.

Comment: But the sum of $x_k^p$ starts at 1 while the sum of the $x_k^q$ starts at m, so it should not be true for all $n_0$ I think.
Or do I overlook something?

Comment: If you had your inequality for all $m$ bigger than a certain $n_0$ you would have, as you said, that the series $\sum_k x_k^q$ diverges. But that's not the case in my example, where both series converge.